# Java httpcleint send SSL request using X.509 certeficate

Tags: java, ssl, https, httpclient

I am sending request to a private service they give me **.crt** , before that on our side I have generated **.csr** and my private key.
So with postman by using my private key and **.crt** certeficate I can send request to the service.
But with my code I am getting SSl handshake exception, I am using JDK 11. This code is creating http client.
So should I do any other steps with certificates?

```
   private static final TrustManager[] tmgs = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[0];
    }
}};

static CloseableHttpClient httpsSSLClient(Env env) {
    try {
        var certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        var x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\cert.crt"));
        var keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        keyStore.load(null, "".toCharArray());
        var trustedCertificateEntry = new KeyStore.TrustedCertificateEntry(x509Certificate);
        keyStore.setEntry("", trustedCertificateEntry, (KeyStore.ProtectionParameter) null);
        var managerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        managerFactory.init(keyStore, "".toCharArray());
        var sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
        sslContext.init(managerFactory.getKeyManagers(), tmgs, null);

        return env.clientBuilder.setSSLContext(sslContext).build();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create httpClient", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
 at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
 at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
 at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314)
 at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293)
 at

Comment: It looks like in Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293) that the reponse can't consumed, because the remote cert (chain) can't be validated. I would import the Truststore from the OS.

Answer (score 0):

First, post please the full exception / stacktrace.

Then I would say, that you don't "import (or) use" the systems or java's truststore.

```
class TrustedCAsByOperatingSystem extends AbstractCaLoader implements Supplier<Collection<X509Certificate>> {
  protected Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
  private static String[] linuxTrustStoreLocation = {"/etc/pki/java/cacerts"};

  @Override
  public Collection<X509Certificate> get() {
    final Collection<X509Certificate> retval = new ArrayList<>();
    this.log.trace("Operating System " + OsUtils.runningOS + " determined.");
    try {
      final TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
      switch (OsUtils.runningOS) {
        case WIN:
          try {
            this.log.info("Trying to load Trusted CAs from Windows Truststore.");
            final KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-ROOT");
            ks.load(null); // You don't need the KeyStore instance to come from a file.
            tmf.init(ks);
            retval.addAll(this.getTrustedCAs(tmf));
          } catch (final Exception e) {
            this.log.warn("Error while loading Trusted CAs from Windows Truststore.", e);
          }
        case UNIX: {
          try {
            FileInputStream myKeys = null;
            for (final String location : TrustedCAsByOperatingSystem.linuxTrustStoreLocation)
              try {
                myKeys = FileUtils.openInputStream(new File(location));
                this.log.info("Trying to load Trusted CAs from Linux Truststore [" + location + "].");
              } catch (final Exception e) {
              }
            if (myKeys != null) {
              final KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
              ks.load(myKeys, "changeit".toCharArray());
              myKeys.close();
              tmf.init(ks);
              retval.addAll(this.getTrustedCAs(tmf));
            }
          } catch (final Exception e) {
            this.log.warn("Error while loading Trusted CAs from Linux Truststore.", e);
          }
        }
        default:
          break;
      }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
      this.log.warn("Error while loading Trusted CAs.", e);
    }
    return this.interceptCa(retval, "OS:" + OsUtils.runningOS);
  }


}
```

Comment: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
 at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131)
 at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
 at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:314)
 at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:293)
 at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:18